# Any Syntactical error

Tags: android

I found source of an application of adt and i imported in android studio, after the Gradle build there shown an single error in java code....i dont know whether it is syntactical or symantic...can u please rectify

```
    String str2;
    if (arrayOfString[i].contains("%")) {
        str2 = arrayOfString[i].split("%")[1];
    }
    String str1;
    for (Settingss.this.setnum = (Settingss.this.setnum + str2 + ","); ; Settingss.this.setnum = (Settingss.this.setnum + str1 + ","))
    {
            i++;
            break;
            str1 = arrayOfString[i];
    }
```

The error occured at 6th line at "str2"..android studio quoted that "str2" may not have been initialized.

This is not the full code, it is just at the error part.

Comment: why are there semicolons in for loop

Comment: for this for statement......

Comment: just make String str2 = "";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change `String str2` to `String str2 = null;`

the reason Android Studio is throwing the error is because the variable could be declared but never initialized i.e. `str2 = XXX;`

Comment: you should make str="". look in the for loop "Settingss.this.setnum + str2 + ",""     if str2 is null and it not initialized form the if wont he get a null pointer

Comment: yup the error gone but it the error followed to str1=arrayOfString[i];    it is saying unreachable statement.